# Flash CS4 Rotating Around Z Axis Without Distorting For Stage Center, Is It Possible?

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, flash-cs4, perspectivecamera

I've got three boxes rotating around their Z axis respectively.  What I'm trying to do  is keep them rotating around their respective Z axis without distorting if I move them away from the center of my stage.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateBoxes);

function rotateBoxes(e:Event):void
{
    box1.rotationY-=10;
    box2.rotationY+=10;
    box3.rotationY-=10;
}
```

example here http://www.hupcapstudios.com/tween1.swf

is there a built in parameter like...

```
box1.globalPerspective = false;
```

it's more noticeable rotating around the x axis

example [http://www.hupcapstudios.com/tweenXswf](http://www.hupcapstudios.com/tweenX.swf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the perspectiveProjection of your clip to its center... see:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/geom/PerspectiveProjection.html#projectionCenter

Something like this should work if the registration point of your clip is at its center:

```
var pp:PerspectiveProjection=new PerspectiveProjection();
pp.projectionCenter = new Point(clip.width/2,clip.height/2);
clip.transform.perspectiveProjection = pp;
```